# Narrowing TypeScript index type

Tags: typescript

I have the following code that should compile, while it's not:

```
interface A {
    field: string;
    fieldB: { fieldC: string;}
}

function mixPropValue<P extends keyof A>(propName: P, value: A[P]) {
    if (propName === 'fieldB') {
        // value is always in type of { fieldC:string }
        value.fieldC; // Error: Property 'fieldC' does not exist on type 'A[P]'.
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20field%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fieldB%3A%20%7B%20fieldC%3A%20string%3B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20mixPropValue%3CP%20extends%20keyof%20A%3E(propName%3A%20P%2C%20value%3A%20A%5BP%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(propName%20%3D%3D%3D%20'fieldB')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20value%20here%20is%20always%20in%20type%20of%20%7B%20fieldC%3Astring%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value.fieldC%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Property%20'fieldC'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'A%5BP%5D'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Is it possible to let TypeScript know the type narrowing under first `if` branch? Of course I can get the code compiling using type casting, but I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can narrow the type in the same hit as checking the property name in order to resolve the type to the narrower option:

```
interface A {
    field: string;
    fieldB: { fieldC: string;}
}

function isFieldB<P extends keyof A>(propName: P, prop: { fieldC: string } | any): prop is { fieldC: string } {
    return propName === 'fieldB';
}

function mixPropValue<P extends keyof A>(propName: P, value: A[P]) {
    if (isFieldB(propName, value)) {
        value.fieldC;
    }
}
```

A future version of the compiler may make this redundant, but it will be an impressive leap if they do it as there is a reasonable amount of "connecting the dots" here. The TypeScript team often manage it though.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will not narrow types based on suck tests, you best bet is a custom type guard:

```
function isProp<P extends keyof A>(value: A[keyof A], targetProp: P, testProp : keyof A) : value is A[P] {
    return targetProp === testProp;
}
function mixPropValue<P extends keyof A>(propName: P, oldValue: A[P], newValue: A[P]) {
    if (isProp(oldValue, 'fieldB', propName) && isProp(newValue, 'fieldB', propName)) {
        // oldValue, newValue here are always in type of { fieldC:string }
        return { ...oldValue, ...newValue }; // Error: Spread types may only be created from object types.
    }
    return newValue;
}
```